# SuperMicro H8QG6-F Rev. 1.01 Motherboard - are AMD 6200 and 6300 series Opteron CPUs supported?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

SuperMicro H8QG6-F **revision 1.01** motherboard - are AMD 6200 and 6300 series Opteron CPUs supported? On official SuperMicro site I can find the information, that these motherboards support 6200 and 6300 series Opterons with new BIOS. But on the Internet there is some information, that **only 6100 series are supported**. Perhaps someone have some experience with this revision of PCB? I have sent this question to SuperMicro - but they do not answer it, support is zero. I need to run those Bulldozers :)

Comment: If the answer is in their website already I don't see the point in replying saying the same. Check the BIOS/UEFI version and update it if necessary.

Comment: No, they do not tell about PCB revisions. But some people claims that Rev 1.01 does not support 6200 or 6300 G34 series. And some says that it supports, but BIOS should be updated. So here I'm confused. The best answer would be from the owner of such board.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis So ask [SuperMIcro support.](https://www.supermicro.com/support/contact.cfm)

Comment: I asked - no answer - a week passed, silence.

Comment: Perhaps you may get more information if you posted on the Hardware stack..

Comment: Yes, I have done already - on "Hardware recommendations" - the question was put on hold... :) And they recommended to ask on Super  User..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can confirm - at least its working with 6200 series Opteron CPUs, tested. So 6300 should also work I think with latest BIOS. Now "Buldozers" doing their work :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally PCB revisions have no impact on CPU compatibility, as their purpose [is generally to improve manufacturing or fix bugs.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53316/when-to-change-a-pcb-number-and-when-to-change-the-revision) As Supermicro hasn't specifically called out any such changes, I'm going to suspect that there aren't any.

More generally, 6200 and 6300 CPUs are compatible, but you may need to update your BIOS. Though I couldn't find any info on 6200 series CPUs per Supermicro, they do state

> BIOS R 3.0 or later is required to support AMD's 6300 series processors

The H8QG6-F was used in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAuOmJVZeQI&feature=youtu.be&t=4m51s) and required a BIOS update to get Opteron 6276 CPUs working. While it's possible that the newer rev ships with a newer BIOS, I wouldn't count on it–especially since in said video the BIOS revisions appears to have been reported incorrectly.

Comment: "Generally PCB revisions have no impact on CPU compatibility" - can disagree. I had Lenovo ThinkCentre M72E motherboard Rev. 1.01 - and it can run only second generation Intel CPU. But Rev. 4.2 - can run both 2nd and 3rd generation CPUs.. Tested.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis Thus the generally. That's also a bit of an interesting case since it came from a prebuilt and isn't really intended to be upgraded. Did you flash the BIOS before trying a 3rd gen processor?

Comment: I've tried to load new BIOS on Ver. 1.01, but it didn't worked (something went wrong as I remember). And Lenovo officialy gives such information - they call Lenovo ThinkCentre M72e **Ivy** with new PCB version inside.